# Reusing StorageClass in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Can I use the same storage class for different services - e.g. I am using persistent volumes for Redis, RabbitMQ , Elastic Search on Kubernetes.

Should I create only only storage class if they all require the same provisioner (GCEPersistentDisk) or what is the best practice for creating and managing storage class.

Can I change the storage class of a claim at a later time ?

Thanks, 
Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `StorageClass` from the documentation:

`kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug`

So at a basic level, it defines - who is responsible for creating storage (`provisioner`) and what parameters need to pass and things such as reclaim policy and so on.

So the number of storage classes you need is dependent characteristics of the underlying storage. As a hypothetical example let's say you had HD and SSD as two types of storages then you would create corresponding two storage classes.

To answer specific questions:

> Can I use the same storage class for different services - e.g. I am
>   using persistent volumes for Redis, RabbitMQ , Elastic Search on
>   Kubernetes.

Yes

> Can I change the storage class of a claim at a later time ?

In practice, No